# Tableview is not displaying any cells or rows content in new pushed viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'm trying to display a new viewController and passing some data to it, but the problem is when this new viewController gets pushed it doesn't display the cells or rows content like labels, textfields and so on..

This is how I'm pushing from one controller to another..

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        BillComparatorViewController *vc = [[BillComparatorViewController alloc] init];
        vc.selectedInstitution = [self.myInstitution objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        [self.view endEditing:YES];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }
```

Then in my new pushed view controller this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath function..

```
//UITableView Delegate + Datasource
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGFloat i = [[self.rowHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];

    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 280, 15)];
    cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFONTNAME size:kSystemFontSizeRows];


    if ([[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFONTNAME size:kSystemFontSizeRows];


        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:arrow];

    }
    else if (i > kTableRowHeight)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = nil;
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, kElementWidth/2, 75)];
        lbl.text = [self.labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl.font = _myFont;
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
        lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

        if ([[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }

        if ([[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            // Can make a class for this cell's contentview, however it never repeats in code
            UITextField* txtField = [self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            txtField.textColor = kBlueColor;
            txtField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter; // iOS 6 support

            NSString *imageName = @"image";
            NSString *arrowName = @"image1";
            if (selectedRow == indexPath.row)
            {
                imageName = @"image";
                arrowName = @"image1";
                txtField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }

            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2*kElementWidth/3 -12, 23, 135, 27)];
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

            UIImageView *arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kElementWidth+10, 31, 8.5, 10)];
            arrowView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrowName];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:arrowView];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtField];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = _myFontSmall;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = kBlueColor;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        if ([[self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            // Can make a class for this cell's contentview, however it never repeats in code
            UITextField* txtField = [self.tableViewElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            txtField.textColor = kBlueColor;
            txtField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter; // iOS 6 support

            NSString *imageName = @"image";
            NSString *arrowName = @"image1";
            if (selectedRow == indexPath.row)
            {
                imageName = @"image";
                arrowName = @"image2";
                txtField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }

            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2*kElementWidth/3 -12, 12, 135, 27)];
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

            UIImageView *arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kElementWidth+10, 20, 8.5, 10)];
            arrowView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrowName];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:arrowView];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtField];
        }

        if (isSearching)
        {
            cellLabel.text = [searchElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

It's a bit long sorry but I think it was important to post it..

**UPDATE**

This is how the problem happens, when user select a row within the current viewcontroller **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** calls a new viewcontroller and pushes this controller but if the user does this while searching with the keyboard in the screen is when the problem happens that the new viewcontroller pushed doenst show any content in its tableview..

**SOLVED**
Within my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
[cell setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: What's the point of re-selecting and then de-selecting the row? Also, what's the point of popViewControllerAnimated: then pushViewControllerAnimated:? I would also expect that to cause an error, something along the lines of unbalanced appearance calls or something like that.

Comment: sorry, my mistake Its the only way I found it to work.. but It's totally incorrect, I didn't mean to publish that, just fixed it

Comment: Also, what's with removing all of the subviews of the cell? I think you're doing a WHOLE lot of work to avoid subclassing UITableViewCell. It looks like you have a few different layouts, make a UITableViewCell subclass for each and make life easier for yourself =)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, going back to the problem this is how the problem happens, when user select a row within the current viewcontroller didSelectRowAtIndexPath calls a new viewcontroller and pushes this controller but if the user does this while searching with the keyboard in the screen is when the problem happens that the new viewcontroller pushed doenst show any content in its tableview.. any idea?

Comment: What does "while searching with the keyboard in the screen" mean? Are you using a search bar and search results controller?

Comment: I have a tableview with a bunch of rows which the user selects an specific option and then this option is use in another viewcontroller. So, if the user scrolls to the list of options in the tableview and selects one, the new viewcontroller loads perfectly fine with all the elements in its tableview but if the user is using the searchbar and during the type the results are getting filter decides to choose one then the new viewcontrollers doesnt load anything in its tableview..

Comment: do you provide cell identifier at attribute inspector for the new VIEW CONTROLLER......?

Comment: @RamaniAshish what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Autolayout. I had the same problem with iOS 8 beta. (I know you're not using i OS 8 but still).

Try turning it off. Should sort the issue out.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is initiating the object of BillComparatorViewController.
You do like this .You may get solution

```
BillComparatorViewController *vc = [[BillComparatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"BillComparatorViewController" Bundle:nil];
```